# What does "weapons are easier to handle" mean?

Tags: mass-effect-3

When you switch the difficulty to "Casual" or lower, a description pops up below saying that "weapons are easier to handle." What does this mean? I can think of a few options, but I'd like to know for sure.

Possibilities:

- Less recoil
- Stronger auto-aim
- Increased accuracy
- Faster reloading
- Larger clip-size

Check out my "screenshot" below that the lovely Vanna helped me create:

[image]

Hurray for consoles!

Comment: Thanks for pointing, I never would have seen it otherwise :P I will try SCIENCE on this when I get home.

Comment: My guess: huge auto aim adjustment, and fewer effects from recoil (less muzzle climb and the sort).

Comment: Pointing is the new freehand circle.

Comment: @MBraedley thanks for the term muzzle climb, I couldn't remember what to call that. it doesn't seem to affect auto-aim on PS3.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Easier to handle" means that guns do not have as much **muzzle climb**, so **your aim does not stray upwards under sustained fire**. The bullet spread DOES increase normally as you shoot however, your aim just says where you put it so there's no need to compensate for recoil.

To test this, stand still and fire an Assault Rifle for a second on casual mode and then on normal mode. Your aim will remain the same after 1 second in casual mode, but you'll be looking up in normal mode.

This does not appear to affect clip size, reloading, accuracy, bullet spread or auto-aim at all. There seems to be only one "level" of easier weapons, there's no difference in handling from Normal to Insanity, and Casual and Narrative mode appear to have the same lack of muzzle climb.

Comment: I tested this on PS3 BTW, so if there's a console auto-aim adjustment I should have noticed it.